# Why the time is expressed differently than in English?

Tags: etymology, time

I have compared some colloquial ways in different languages of saying time and what surprised me, is that there are differences between English and German, even though they are from the same language family. So now I am not sure, whether it was English moving away (as in Romance Spanish it's the same as in English) or whether there were historical changes in German. Does the explanation maybe stay in the word `halb` and its grammatical features/meaning? As `halb` is translated as `half of`. So is it caused by grammar, or there was a historical shift?

| Time | English | German | Czech |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1:15 | quarter past one | Viertel nach eins | čtvrt na **dvě** |
| 1:30 | half past one | halb **zwei** | půl **druhé** |
| 1:45 | quarter to **two** | Viertel vor **zwei** | tři čtvrtě na **dvě** |

Comment: The example you wrote in Czech is precisely showing you that English is the exception (in that table). Also in English you are aided by 'past' and in Spanish by 'y', so I think there is completely another system.

Comment: Even different English speaking countries differ in expressing times for example, "half nine" is 9:30 in the UK, but this expression isn't used in the US. There's no reason to expect any consistency between different languages.

Comment: Also, there are regional differences within German speaking countries.

Answer (score 6):

It is true that German and English have a common ancestor, but to find it you have to go back far beyond the era of modern time-keeping. Therefore there is no reason to assume that German and English expressions for it are more similar than for example those between German and the neighbouring language French.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly the expressions

- viertel nach eins
- halb zwei
- viertel vor zwei

are most frequently used in German to speak about time. However, there are alternative variants to say it, so it is neither caused by grammar, nor was there a general historical shift. Quite often you can hear

- *dreiviertel zwei* for 13:45

Some people also say

- *viertel zwei* for 13:15

This is not commonly understood in Germany, perhaps it is a regional thing. My Bavarian relatives use to say it that way.

This shows the logical structure:

*viertel zwei* means *ein viertel der Stunde zwischen eins und zwei* etc.

Comment: Also in and around Berlin we usually say *viertel zwei* and *dreiviertel zwei*, but I know that some people from western regions in Germany have difficulties understanding this way of specifying the time.

Comment: Note that the Czech way is similar to the German variant *viertel zwei* and *dreiviertel zwei*, with the difference that they seem to use the cardinal number (two) with "a quarter" or "three quarters" and the corresponding ordinal number (second) with"half", at least in the example in the screenshot.

Comment: I always assumed the "alternative variant" is due to how church bells indicate time ([Viertelstundenschlag](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uhrschlag#Viertelstundenschlag_(viertel,_halb,_dreiviertel_und_voll))).

Comment: I am downvoting for two reasons: The question is not answered, and it does not help in any way to introduce another complexity. And by the way, I have never encontered a situation where using these _(drei)viertel_ variants successfully conveyed a meaning. Without exception it ended in an argument about which time was actually meant.

Comment: @ccprog "these (drei)viertel variants" are a regional thing. My (East-German) family uses these without any arguments or issues. I got used to the other variant only when I moved to Hamburg as a student. See https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f11e/

Comment: "these (drei)viertel variants are also common in eastern Austria (the east/west boundary being between Upper Austria and Lower Austria).

Comment: See the [entry for the time "10:15" in "Atlas  zur  deutschen  Alltagssprache"](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f11e/)

Comment: A lot of information, but I fail how to see how this addresses the question at all. Question is about diachronic development, your answer is about synchronic diversity / grammar explanation.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach The question is "Does the explanation maybe stay in the word halb and its grammatical features/meaning? As halb is translated as half of. So is it caused by grammar, or there was a historical shift?" If it were a grammatical feature, then it shouldn't have variants which are also grammatically correct (as the variants in my answer where I wrote "so it is neither caused by grammar, nor was there a general historical shift" and" This shows the logical structure").

Comment: I see "So is it caused by grammar, or there was a historical shift?" as the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are simplified. In German there are many variations of how time is used in spoken language.

## 10:15

In English you say: "a quarter past ten". In Germany, Austria and Switzerland there are four different versions in use how to say it:

[image]
<sup>source: [Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f11e/)</sup>

## 10:45

In English you say: "a quarter to eleven". There are also different versions in German, but I do not have so exact informations about the geographic distribution as for 10:15. This is what I know:

- **»viertel vor elf«**
  This seems to be the most frequent used form in Germany and parts of Austria (West of Austria, where about 1/3 of all Austrians live).
- **»dreiviertel elf«**
  This is the standard form in the east of Austria (where 2 of 3 Austrians live). You also find this form in the very south of Germany (close to Austria) but also far away, in the very north of Germany (where *Niederdeutsch* = Low German is spoken). Even in the middle of Germany there are smaller regions where this form is preferred.

During the Habsburg Monarchy these spelling was usual in the whole monarchy which covered not only the region of todays Austria, but also Check Republic, Slovakia, Hungary, Slovenia and even the Burgundian Netherlands:

- 10:15 = ¼11
- 10:30 = ½11
- 10:45 = ¾11

And this still is how these times are used in Austria but also in other countries that where part of Habsburg Monarchy.

Comment: A lot of information, but I fail how to see how this addresses the question at all. Question is about diachronic development, your answer is about synchronic diversity.

Answer (score 0):

> Used also in Old English phrases, as in modern German, to mean "one half unit less than," for example *þridda healf* "two and a half," literally "half third."

> [etymonline.com/word/half]

Note that *semi-professional* is formed similarly to *half an hour*, *halbe Stunde*, adv. *halbstündlich* etc. So "10:30" might appear like one half of the full 11th hour, or one half *off* the full hour, if you will, which is fairly arbitrary.

---

As far as the etymology of *half* is uncertain, chances are this has to do with one fused particle or another, which is a difficult problem across the board because the words are ultra short and were dependent on endings which have been erroded to such a degree that different forms were merged, rebracketed, lost etc.

Beware that despite Romance languages having left a notable imprint in West Germanic languages, as with *hora* vel sim. "hour" (Ger. *Uhr* "clock, o'clock") as well as *passer* "to pass", these appear to be very similar to some of the particles we see in the differential distribution of calling time such as Austrian German *über* "past" which has a cognate in Old Frisian *ur* (with various meanings), which is principally closer to the Old Frankish and early Dutch—more research is needed.